# Weird DC Response in Photodiode TIA Circuit

Tags: analog, photodiode, transimpedance

I'm building a photodetector circuit designed to measure the amplitude of a 1 kHz signal.

[image: schematic].

I have reworked the feedback resistor (R2) to 383 kΩ and changed the bandpass filter to have a gain of 15.

I am using an AD8646, not the AD8606.

The weird response I'm seeing is that the output amplitude of this circuit drops by around 7 mV when there is no dc light source present (the detector is just sitting in the dark). When there is some light around (any sunlight, low levels from house lights), the amplitude pops up again. The drop off does not vary with the intensity of the light, it is a step function response; when the dc light level gets too low, the amplitude drops. The 1 kHz light source was held at a constant amplitude in both cases.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I'd fix it?

Comment: Check that you have pin 1 and pin 3 as shown in your diagram. If you have these reversed then it will do what you say. Also confirm what op-amp you are using; this is important because you have two op-amps in your circuit and a question like this needs good clarity. Also confirm what is the driving source of the node named 2.5 volts AND how you are measuring the amplitude.

Comment: Thanks for catching the op amp issue. I am using an AD8646, not the AD8606. Amplitude is measured using an oscilloscope. 2.5v is created using an AD1582BRTZ-REEL7 series reference.

Comment: Why do you have R4 connected to 2.5 volts? What does R4 do in this circuit? What is the p-p amplitude with and without ambient light - you state it drops by an amount but, actual p-p amplitudes are required. There's a decent chance that using the AD8606 it will be much improved in your problem.

Comment: I designed the filter using the TI WEBENCH filter design tool which calls for R4, it is connected to 2.5v to move the signal to the 2.5v false ground. The dip is actually closer to ~7mv. I have been messing around with a different stages after this for more filtering/ amplification and it got a bit messed up in my head, will edit the post now. A typical p-p in dc light is ~11mv. What features of the AD8606 would improve the circuit? I originally designed this with an AD8606, but when I built the circuit it wasn't in stock and the AD8646 seemed like a pretty good replacement.

Comment: Should the "+" terminal of your PD1 be grounded?

Comment: @Tyler - pin 1 should be grounded in a single rail op-amp TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original design uses an AD8606 op-amp and is one of my favourites. It has a very respectable input offset voltage of typically 80 μV with input voltages right down at the lowest negative rail of the device. Compare this to the much poorer AD8646 that is typically 600 μV and, it is this that I believe, is causing you the problems. In effect the poor offset voltage is "blanking" your small signal and, with no negative supply, the op-amp output will flat-line until the photo-amplitude is enough to break through this barrier (or increased ambient light comes to the rescue).

Other things, R4 connected to 2.5 volts is not happening in this circuit - the 2nd stage op-amp is decoupled from DC hence, it's pointless. Also, the 2nd stage has very high AC gain (due to C10) and this looks in need of redesign to reduce the effects of noise. Why you are using R7 (95 k) and R4 (1k2) to pot down the output of the first stage is a complete and baffling mystery to me. I think you need to revisit the original design produced by TI WEBENCH filter design tool.

Comment: Yes this turned out to be the issue, thanks! Huge oversight on my part. I fixed it by biasing the non inverting input just above the offset voltage. I'll look more into the R4 issue, it seems to be in every WEBENCH multiple feedback bandpass I have tried so far.

Comment: @jfhagler OK, I see it is an MFB bandpass filter now but, the attenuation of the signal is very worrying. You don't need to connect R4 to 2.5 volts either.